# "only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index"

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-slicing

I am generating a numpy array with 1000000 random numbers between 1 and 6 and i would like to calculate the mean of the first 10, 100, 1000, ... I also want to plot the means on logarithmic scale. I mustn't use anything but Python with numpy and matplotlib. Why do i get this error? What have i done wrong?

This is my code:

```
throws=numpy.random.randint(1,7,(1000000))
print(throws[1:10])

x=np.logspace(1,6,6)
plt.plot(x, int(mean(throws[1:x])))
plt.semilogx()
```

Sorry for my bad English and the german variable names...

Comment: which error are you getting ?

Comment: I would avoid using an umlaut in a variable name. Might cause trouble with the interpreter.

Comment: Apparently the interpreter is complaining that you used something as an index that can't be used as an index. I'm guessing this comes from `wurfe[1:x]` with `x=np.logspace(1,6,6)`.

Comment: i'm getting TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost there! You just have to slice the `würfe` (dice throws) array and then apply mean to it, this is easiest with

```py
würfe=numpy.random.randint(1,7,(1000000))
print(würfe[1:10])

x=np.logspace(1,6,6)
y=[np.mean(würfe[:int(x_)]) for x_ in x]  # <--- just add this line
plt.plot(x, y)
plt.semilogx()
plt.show()
```

`x` here is `[10, 100, 1000, 10000, 100000, 1000000]` and `würfe[:int(x_)]` converts `x` from float to int and uses it to slice the original array into the parts you want to take the mean of. The mean is then taken with a [Python list comprehension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34835951/what-does-list-comprehension-mean-how-does-it-work-and-how-can-i-use-it).

[image]

Comment: Thank you sooo much, you made my day

Answer (score 0):

Try Run:

```
import numpy
x=numpy.logspace(1,6,6)
print(x.dtype)
```

Shows

```
float64
```

So `würfe[1:x]` is using `float64` array as index,certainly it can't be right.

Use

```
x=numpy.logspace(1,6,6).astype(int)
```

And also `würfe[1:x]` requires x to be a int but not an array.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but it doesn't change anything... Do you have another advice/ idea where the problem is caused?

Comment: The problem occurs at the `würfe[1:x]`, because x is an array not a number (scalar). Try using each member of x individually: `[würfe[:x_] for x_ in x]`